# How do I import a jpg image in java?

Tags: java, image, jpanel

I wanted to import a image in java, and I have no idea how to do it. I need someone to show me how. I wanted to import a jpg image I found on google, I tried and a lot example code online but none of them works for me. The application I use for programming my code is by using eclipse. P.S I use a mac.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "import" here?

Comment: We have no idea what you're asking especially when there is no code sample to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to add images in my program

Comment: You need to give more information about what you are trying to do, what classes or libraries you are trying to use, and so on.  Are you trying to load images so that you can show them in your application, e.g., a Swing application?  Are you trying to load images so you can process them somehow and then write them out to disk?  Just "add images" is too vague.

Comment: I wanted to do a program where I ask the user a question for example: what is 7/2=?, and if the user get it right a picture/image will pop up from the Jpanel.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've tagged `JPanel` in your question, I'm going to assume that you're using swing. You can add an image to a `JLabel` like so:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.net.URL;

// inside your class constructor/method
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://image...."));
JLabel jlPic = new JLabel(img);

panel.add(jlPic);
```

If your image is on your computer instead of from a URL, you can simply pass a `String` path to that image to the constructor of `ImageIcon` instead.

Comment: I'm not going to write your whole program for you. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: :(, will then I have no idea on how to do it. I tried every youtube video there is for how to display a jpg image on java but non of it actually works.... D: